# Highlight difference between 2 arrays / database rows

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am attempting to create a script which will highlight when a row column has changed in the database. I have determined (possibly due to lack of knowledge) that using `array_diff` would be a good way of accomplishing this.

I have this working for the most part, except I am getting an error on the very last row.

Here is the code which creates an array containing the differences between the current table row and the next one:

```
function fetchDiffs () {
    $sql = $this->main_sql."
            order by lh.date_created desc";
    $stm = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $stm->bindParam(':id_lead', $this->id_lead);
    $stm->execute();
    $res = $stm->fetchAll();

    if ($res) {
        array_walk_recursive($res, 'sanitize');         
        $diffs = array();
        foreach ($res as $k => $v) {
            if (array_key_exists($k+1, $res)) {
                $diffs[$v['id']] = array_diff($v, $res[$k+1]);
            }
        }
        $this->diffs = $diffs;
    }
}
```

What this does is create an array of fields whose values have changed when compared to the next row, and uses the row id as the primary array key.

Here is the code I use to highlight the `postcode` row when its value is different in the next row, based on the code above:

```
if (array_key_exists('postcode', $this->diffs[$this->row['id']])) 
    echo ' class="warning"';
```

I should mention this is part of a class, which is why you're seeing `$this->`.

Now, this code is producing the following error on the very last row:

> Notice: Undefined offset

I'm assuming this is because it has no row to compare it to being that it is the last one. However, I would have thought that the following code would prevent this:

```
if (array_key_exists($k+1, $res)) {
```

But it doesn't. How do I fix this? I'm at a loss here, possibly due to lack of sleep.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It means one array is smaller than the other, or perhaps one array's index starts at `0` and the other `1` (or another number, this is just an example). Do a `var_dump()` of each array and add them to your post so we can delve deeper into your issue.

Comment: They are the exact same array. I am simply doing a comparison by offsetting the array in the second array_diff parameter by 1 element.